# How best to implement document storage and editing with xml in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, xslt, xml-parsing

I'm working on a project that involves the writing and saving of simple reports. It is required to be web based and I have decided to build it with rails. I have also decided that that the reports shall be saved as xml files and not in a database. 
The interface for this project will also require dynamically built forms, as the reports will contain differing amounts of information.

After doing some research, I think this should be implemented via some XSLT/Javascript to help build the forms from the given XML and some Ruby/Ajax to save/edit the reports. Does this sound like a good approach? Are there any best practices for this sort of thing? Any other ideas or sources of information would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.